# Keras ImageDatagenerator Load Images from one Subfolder

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anomaly-detection, imagedatagenerator

I want to code an image anomaly detection with autoencoder.

Therefore I splitted my images into one subfolder for trainining images, one for validation images and one for anomaly images.

```
history = model.fit(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=500 // batch_size,
    epochs=1000,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=75 // batch_size,
    shuffle=True)
```

For `model.fit` I need an seperated `train_generator` and `validation_generator`

For getting train_generator I am using this one.

```
train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'C:/Python/Anomaly_dection_V1/cell_images/Uninfected_Train/',
    target_size=(SIZE, SIZE),
    color_mode='rgb',
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='input',
)
```

So I take the images directly from the subfolder, where just images and no other folders are located.

Sadly I get the following message:
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.

Can anyone help me out?

If I take one folder above instead of the subfolder, it can find images from three classes.
But for the model.fit I need just the train data and the validatio data. I didnt find any solution just to use the subfolders/classes for that.

Is `flow_from_directory` not working to get images from just one subfolder?

Comment: Why not just separate the training, validation and anomaly classes to a training, validation and anomaly folder?

Comment: Thats what I did. On my computer I created 3 subfolders: Uninfected_Train, Uninfected_Test, Parasitized (Train, Validation, Anomaly). And now I wanted to load those data seperately. But it was just possible to load them combined from one folder above, but I dont know how to seperate them later.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the specific single folder images using `image_dataset_from_directory` by specifying the `labels = None` as below:

This way you can also split the dataset of that folder into train and validation portion using `validation_split=0.2`.

```
data_dir  = "/content/drive/MyDrive/data/PetImages/Cat"

# in your case: data_dir = "C:/Python/Anomaly_dection_V1/cell_images/Uninfected_Train"
```

Training data :

```
train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  labels = None,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

Output:

```
Found 12500 files belonging to 1 classes.
Using 10000 files for training.
```

Validation dataset:

```
val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  labels = None,
  label_mode=None,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

Output:

```
Found 12500 files belonging to 1 classes.
Using 2500 files for validation.
```